# Regex first character not matching

Tags: java, regex, find, match

I am having some Java Pattern problems. This is my pattern:

```
"^[\\p{L}\\p{Digit}~._-]+$"
```

It matches any letter of the US-ASCII, numerals, some special characters, basically anything that wouldn't scramble an URL.

What I would like is to find the first letter in a word that does not match this pattern. Basically the user sends a text as an input and I have to validate it  and to throw an exception if I find an illegal character.

I tried negating this pattern, but it wouldn't compile properly. Also `find()` didn't help out much.

A legal input would be `hello` while `?hello` should not be, and my exception should point out that `?` is not proper.

I would prefer a suggestion using Java's Matcher, Pattern or something using `util.regex`. Its not a necessity, but checking each character in the string individually is not a solution.

Edit: I came up with a better regex to match unreserved URI characters

Comment: `!"?hello".subString(0,1).matches("^[\\p{L}\\p{Digit}.'-.'_]+$")`?

Comment: Can you share some code on what you are trying to do? Trying to sanitize the GET/POST params? Or the entire URL?

Comment: Why use 2 `'` and `.` in a single character class? Also, the `'-.` creates a range (and matches `'()*+,-.`), is it on purpose? BTW, try `if (str.matches("[^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}.'_-].*")) { /* Error! */ }`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor for the observation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
^[\\p{L}\\p{Digit}.'-.'_]*([^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}.'-.'_]).*$
```

The first character non matching is the group n°1

I made a few try here : http://fiddle.re/gkkzm6[1](http://fiddle.re/bkx696)

**Explanation :**

I negate your pattern, so i built this :

```
[^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}.'-.'_]      [^...] means every character except for
^                       ^             the following ones.
|  your pattern inside  |
```

The pattern has 3 parts :

```
^[\\p{L}\\p{Digit}.'-.'_]*
```

Checks the regex from the first character until he meets a non matching character

```
([^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}.'-.'_])
```

The non-matching character (negation) inside a capturing group

```
.*$
```

Any character until the end of the string.

Hope it helps you

**EDIT :**

The correct regex shoud be :

```
^[\\p{L}\\p{Digit}~._-]*([^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}~._-]).*$
```

It is the same method, i only change the contents of the first and second part.

I tried and it seems to work.

Comment: I would call it the accepted answer, but my initial regex wasn't doing its job properly, so I edited the question

Comment: based on your suggestion and after my edit, I think this should be the correct negative matcher: `"^[\\p{L}\\p{Digit}~._-]*([^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}~._-]).*$"`

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one to find the first non valid char:

```
Pattern negPattern = Pattern.compile(".*?([^\\p{L}^\\p{Digit}^.^'-.'^_]+).*");
Matcher matcher = negPattern.matcher("hel?lo");
if (matcher.matches())
{
    System.out.println("'" + matcher.group(1).charAt(0) + "'");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, really unintuitive way this java Matcher works

Answer (score 0):

The `"^[\\p{L}\\p{Digit}.'-.'_]+$"` pattern matches any string containing 1+ characters defined inside the character class. Note that double `'` and `.` are suspicious and you might be unaware of the fact that `'-.` creates a range and matches `'()*+,-.`. If it is not on purpose, I think you meant to use `.'_-`.

To check if a string starts with a character other than the one defined in the character class, you can negated the character class, and check the first character in the string only:

```
if (str.matches("[^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}.'_-].*")) {
   /* String starts with the disallowed character */ 
}
```

I also think you can shorten the regex to `"(?U)[^\\w.'-].*"`. At any rate, `\\p{Digit}` can be replaced with `\\d`.